# Значення слів "лем", "тя", "шом", "бим" з пісні "Америцький край"

Tags: діалектизми, лемківський-діалект

Допоможіть розібратись з ділектом що звучить в пісні ["Світозари - Америцький край"](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/870312.html).

В пісні є багато невідомих мені слів, які можна зрозуміти з контексту, але є і такі, що не вдається - як то "лем", "тя", "шом" або "бим".

> Полетів бим на край світа,
>
> Як тот вітер в полі літа,
>
> Гей, в америцький край.
>
> Лем жаль ми тя, моя хижо,
>
> Лем жаль ми тя, моя хижо,
>
> Солом'яная жаль.

**Питання:** Допоможіть зрозуміти ці слова і загалом текст пісні. Звідки цей діалект? Чи використовується він зараз?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, оформлюйте кожне шукане слово окремим запитанням. Також, прохання не забувати, що продемонстрована спроба самостійно знайти відповідь на запитання значно покращує якість самого запитання.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Панова [ланка](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/870312.html) містить відомости під словами пісні: [лемківські](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8) пісні. Відти нескладно здогадати: чи [говір](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80), чи [мова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) лемків.

Важко судити про теперішній вжив, бо дії [Вісли](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%92%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%C2%BB) надто сильно підкосили їх, через цього вони вимушені були виживати будь-яким чином, в тому числі і приживання до инших народностей. В Україні наразі вживають переважно як пісні — особливо набули широкої відомости після 13 року (прошчальні). Також чував про деяких товариствах в Польшчі. Зазначу шче відому лемкиню — [Квітка Цісик](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A6%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA).

[Зміст](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/ukrainian-folk-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9-lyrics.html) слів

**лем** — тільки, лишень (в даному випадку, бо саме слово може приймати багато значень, у залежності від контексту)
**ми тя** — мені тебе
**бим** — [би](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/121/585)
**шом** — віддієсловане *шчо* по *я*, цебто *шчо я*